# Navigation Drawer overlap with BubblePicker view?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, bubble-popup

I am using a bubble picker library for bubble animation  and a material drawer library for navigation bar .

I am facing a issue where the bubble picker view is getting overlap with the navigation drawer.What might be the issue and how can i resolve it .

here is a bubble picker code in my layout

```
<com.igalata.bubblepicker.rendering.BubblePicker
    android:id="@+id/Bubblepick"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    app:backgroundColor="#f1ff78"/>
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`setZOrderOnTop(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)) to bubble picker

```
picker = findViewById(R.id.picker);
picker.setZOrderOnTop(false);
```

Comment: Hi @i_m_mahii above given solution made my the bubbles invisible,
they are thr but invisible , can you help?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the bubble picker is being rendered on top of the drawer. What does your layout look like that includes the drawer? If the library always renders on top of everything, then you will probably need to toggle the visibility while the drawer is open using bubblePickerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: My layout in drawer is very standard have some icons in the navigation bar with textview . Setting a view to Invisible is not a good option ,will make ui look strange. Any option's to make the bubble picker view below the navigation drawer?

Comment: Post your entire layout xml